# AWS CLI permission denied?

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I recently downloaded AWS CLI for Windows. I was able to use it just fine the first day however it is now giving me a Permission Denied error on Git Bash whenever I try to do anything with aws.

```
$ aws

bash: /c/Program Files/Amazon/AWSCLIV2/aws: Permission denied
```

I've tried uninstalling, reinstalling, restarting my computer, and still nothing. I've even tried messing with the permissions on the folder but it still says I dont even have permission to do that. 
Any help?

Comment: Seems like you are not running as administrator. Your local user might not have permission to 'c/Program Files/Amazon/AWSCLIV2/aws'

Comment: Run your terminal as administrator

Comment: You can also try to change the permission of this execution file, not sure if it's possible in Windows.

Comment: It was a problem with Carbon Black and my employer's IT department saying that it was a false positive. This was solved. Thanks y'all.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this was caused by an AV Agent, specifically Carbon Black, identifying the CLI executable as a threat. Obviously this is a false positive and an issue with Carbon Black.

To resolve the problem I disabled "Protection" temporarily, did what I needed to do, and then uninstalled the CLI until I can get a hold of the responsible party within our organization. I'm also planning to submit this to CB.

Here's how to disable protection:

- Find the Carbon Black icon in the bottom right-hand corner of the taskbar.
- Right-click the icon and then select Open.

> [image: CB Agent Icon]

- In the CB Agent window, you should see a "Protection" toggle at the top right. Click **Off**

> [image: CB Agent Window]

You should now be able to install the AWS CLI, or use it if you had already installed it.